# How to get record numpy array with dates from pandas data frame?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that I would like to transform into a numpy record array. `df.to_records()` works fine except one column in which I have datetime values. As a result of `df.to_records()` i get:

```
[(1275264000000000000L, 9912.0, 58450.0, 1036, 136.0, 15.0)
 (1275264000000000000L, 9912.0, 155471.0, 1033, 1033.0, 15.0)
 (1275264000000000000L, 9912.0, 166784.0, 1011, 111.0, 2.0)
 (1275264000000000000L, 9912.0, 166798.0, 10106, 1111.0, 12.0)]
```

The first values in each tuple are expected to be dates, but they are something else. Their date type is `'<M8[ns]'` (I do not know what it means).

Does anybody know how can I get a record array that contain dates?

Comment: These represent May 31 2010 in nanoseconds (ns) since the Unix epoch. Is that the date you're expecting?

Comment: I would like to have a date object instead of number of nanoseconds.

Comment: And yes, May 31, 2010 is the date that I expect.

Comment: I believe these are already datetimes and this is just a detail of record representation. An array with dtype='<M8[ns]' shows datetimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's merely a representation:

```
>>> df
                    0     1
0 2010-05-31 00:00:00  9912
1 2010-05-31 00:00:00  9912
>>> df.to_records()
rec.array([(0L, 1275264000000000000L, 9912.0),
           (1L, 1275264000000000000L, 9912.0)],
      dtype=[('index', '<i8'), ('0', '<M8[ns]'), ('1', '<f8')])
```

But

```
>>> df.to_records()[0][1]
numpy.datetime64('2010-05-31T04:00:00.000000000+0400')
```

Type `<M8[ns]` is one of numpy's [datetime](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html#datetimes-and-timedeltas) types, ns stands for storing data in nanoseconds since the epoch.

```
>>> np.datetime64().dtype
dtype('<M8')
```